# C: add a polynomial term to a linked list in the increasing order of exponents

Tags: c, linked-list, polynomials

Hi I'm new to c programming and not familiar with the linked list. 
Here I want to write a function addPolyTerm() that takes two integers(coefficient and exponent) as inputs and add them to the existing polynomial by degree. I also have a function to display the polynomial. I've tried many times, this is the best version I got.

```
//assimilate new term into the existing polynomial
int addPolyTerm(int coeff, int expo) {
    struct PolyTerm* newTerm = (struct PolyTerm *)malloc(sizeof(struct PolyTerm));
    if(newTterm == NULL) return -1;
    newTerm -> coeff = coeff;
    newTerm -> expo = expo;
    newTerm -> next = NULL;

    Struct PolyTerm *term1, *term2;
    if(head == NULL) head = newTerm;  //the linked list is empty
    else {
        term1 = head;
        //move forward when the new expo is larger than the previous one
        while(term1 != NULL && term1->expo < expo) { 
            term2 = term1;
            term1 = term1->next;            
        }
        //merge polynomial terms with the same exponent
        if(term1 != NULL && term1->expo == expo) {
            term1->coeff += coeff;
        }
        else{
            term2->next = newTerm;
            newTerm->next = term1;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The input text is (left: coefficient, right: exponent):

```
12 3
0 2
4 5
```

expected output:

```
0x2+12x3+4x5
```

but my output is:

```
12x3+4x5
```

It seems like my function didn't handle the condition where the expo is smaller than that of the previous term. How could I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `term2` is not assigned a value when `head->expo >= expo`.

Comment: So what should I do? assign term2==NULL?

Comment: Yes, and if `term2` is still NULL after the loop, then you need to put the `newTerm` at the beginning of the list.

Comment: You can then conflate the two cases where the list head is null and where the new exponent is the smallest. (By the way, when you combine two nodes with the same exponent, you should free the now useless new node so that you don't leak memory.)

Comment: @user3386109 How do I put the `newTerm` at the beginning? Would it become the new head? I'm confused:(

Comment: @MOehm Could you tell why you suggested that? and how do I free the useless new node?

Comment: Because when you insert a new node (as opposed to modifying the coeff of an existing node), there are really just two cases: Either you insert at the front by modifying the head or you insert after another node by modifying its next pointer. Adding to an empty list is really just a special case of ading at the front. (The new node's next will be the old head, and in this case it's null.) Fewer cases means less code, which is nice.

Comment: You free the useless new node with `free(newTerm)` after `term1->coeff += coeff`, just as you free the nodes of your list at the end of your program. (You do that, don't you?) A nicer solution might be to check whether the exponents match before you create a new node, so that you only create it when it's needed. [Here's](https://ideone.com/Gvq4BO) hoew that could look like.